# Django error: io.UnsupportedOperation: read and ValueError: bad mode 'rb'

Tags: python, django

I was getting this error: **io.UnsupoortedOperation: read**
I made some changes. I changed this line `img = Image.open(f)` to `img = Image.open(f, "rb")` After that I get this error: **ValueError: bad mode 'rb'**
What's the problem here? How do I fix this?

views.py

```
class LinkCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Link
    form_class = LinkForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        hash = str(uuid.uuid1())
        with open("tmp_img_original_{}.png".format(hash), "wb") as f:
            res = requests.get(form.instance.url, stream=True)
            if not res.ok: raise Exception("URL'de dosya yok: 404")
            for block in res.iter_content(1024): f.write(block)

            img = Image.open(f, "rb")
            width, height = img.size
            img.thumbnail(get_size(width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img.save()

            djfile = File(f)

            form.img.save("img_tn_{}.png".format(hash), djfile, save=True)
            f.close()

        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.rank_score = 0.0
        f.submitter = self.request.user
        f.save()

        return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is open the file with mode "wb+"

Change this

```
with open("tmp_img_original_{}.png".format(hash), "wb") as f:
```

to

```
with open("tmp_img_original_{}.png".format(hash), "wb+") as f:
```